# Fragment's content above Tab's text in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout and I attach two tabs.

```
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Featured"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Filter"));
```

Then `onTabSelected()` I display the fragment I want according to which tab user selected.

The layout of my Activity is :

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/ll_container" 
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fl_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout of the fragments is just a TextView in a LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:text="Projects List Fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But the result I get is the following :

[image]

as you can see the content of the fragment overlaps Tab's text when it should appear underneath. 
Thanks

Comment: use `RelativeLayout` as perent view and `android:layout_below` attribute in `FrameLayout`

Comment: @Mohit just tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: post the code where you are calling fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found alternative solution for this problem.

You can give top padding on your each Tab fragment's layout.

Eg,

android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

For instance, my first tab xml looks like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.upgautam.uddhav.productassignment.uicontrollers.ProductListFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/product_list_string" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now, the screen looks like below:
[image]